# How to get last 10 mins records using linq?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I want to write LINQ query from last 10 mins inserted records from table. How do I write it? Please help me.

Below is my SQL query:

```
SELECT AccountNumber, OrderID,RechargeDate 
FROM    OrderItem OI
WHERE RechargeStatus = 'SUCCESS' 
  AND AccountNumber ='" + AccountNumber + "' and DateADD(minute, -10,getdate() ) < RechargeDate  AND OrderItemID <> " + OrderItemID + "";
```

Now, I want to rewrite the query above using LINQ.

Comment: you should try yourself before asking

Comment: Or use Linqer :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `Where` linq extension method.

```
db.OrderItems.Where(x => x.RechargeStatus.Equals("SUCCESS") && 
                         x.AccountNumber == strAccountNumber &&
                         x.RechargeDate > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10) &&
                         x.OrderItemID != OrderItemID )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way:

```
db.OrderItems.Where(x=>x.RechargeStatus.Equals("SUCCESS") && 
                   x.AccountNumber == strAccountNumber &&
                   x.RechargeDate >= DateTime.Now().AddMinutes(-10) &&
                   x.OrderItemID != OrderItemID )
```

it's returned till last 10 minutes created records. i have checked greater than equal.